rotate text from head section - jspdf-autotable
I need to rotate the text from the head array in the pdf.autotable.
When I try the following code, I get the text displayed in both vertical and horizontal direction, but I only want the vertical alignment.
This is my code:
pdf.autoTable({
          head: [
            [
              "DATUM",
              "BP KRANK",
              "STUNDEN NORM",
              "STUNDEN SPÄT",
              "STUNDEN WE",
              "STUNDEN NACHT",
              "FRÜHSTÜCK",
              "ZNÜNI",
              "MITTAG",
              "ZVIERI",
              "ABENDESSEN",
              "KILOMETER",
              "DIVERSES",
              "JG / MAG",
            ],
          ],
          body,
          startY: pdf.previousAutoTable.finalY + 5,
          margin: {right: 5, left: 5},
          theme: "grid",
          styles: {halign: "center", fontSize: 8},
          headStyles: {
            fillColor: [211, 211, 211],
          },
          columnStyles: {
            0: {cellWidth: 15.38, fillColor: [218, 233, 212]},
            1: {cellWidth: 15.38, fillColor: [217, 225, 242]},
            2: {cellWidth: 15.38},
            3: {cellWidth: 15.38, fillColor: [246, 203, 204]},
            4: {cellWidth: 15.38, fillColor: [243, 243, 243]},
            5: {cellWidth: 15.38, fillColor: [254, 255, 153]},
            6: {cellWidth: 15.38},
            7: {cellWidth: 15.38},
            8: {cellWidth: 15.38},
            9: {cellWidth: 15.38},
            10: {cellWidth: 15.38},
            11: {cellWidth: 15.38},
            12: {cellWidth: 15.38},
            13: {cellWidth: 15.38, fillColor: [217, 225, 242]},
          },
          didDrawCell: function(data) {
            const doc = data.doc;
            if (data.section === "head") {
              const text = data.cell.raw;
              const x = data.cell.x + data.cell.width / 2;
              const y = data.cell.y + data.cell.height / 2;
              doc.setFontSize(8);
              doc.text(text, x, y, null, 90);
            }
          },
        });

How can I solve the problem.
Thx.
Sample Image
